# Use switch statement after if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

I want to use `switch` statement after an `if` statement but I can't and I don't know what is the problem.

```
public class main {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        String input; //To hold user's input.
        char selectPackage; //To hold Internet Package
        double hourUsage, totalCharges, addCharges; //other variables

        //Create a Scanner object for keyboard input.
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Prompt the user to select a Internet Package.
        System.out.print("Which package did you purchase? ( Enter the Package's letter)");
        input = keyboard.nextLine();
        selectPackage = input.charAt(0);

        System.out.print("Please select the amount of hours used.");
        input = keyboard.nextLine();
        hourUsage = Double.parseDouble(input);

        //Display pricing for selected package...
        switch (selectPackage)
        {
            case 'a':
            case 'A':
                if (hourUsage > 10)
                {
                    addCharges = hourUsage - 10;
                    totalCharges = (addCharges * 2.0) + 9.95;
                    System.out.println("You have used " + hourUsage + " hours and your total is $" + 
                    totalCharges + " per month. ");
                }
                else
                    System.out.println("Your total is $9.95 per month.");
                break;

            case 'b':
            case 'B':
                if (hourUsage > 20 )
                { 
                    addCharges = hourUsage - 20;
                    totalCharges = (addCharges * 1.0) + 13.95;
                    System.out.println("You have used " + hourUsage + " and your total is $" + totalCharges + " per month.");
                }    
                else
                    System.out.println("Your total is $13.95 per month.");
                break;

            case 'c':
            case 'C':
                System.out.println("Your total is $19.95 per month.");
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid Choice. Choice A,B,C");
        }
    }
}

System.out.println("Your total is $19.95 per month.");

}
else
     System.out.println("Your total is $19.95 per month.");

}
}
```

Now I want to use the `switch` statement for telling user that if he/she chose package "B", he would save 20 dollars.

Comment: Where do you want to use that switch?  At the very bottom?

Comment: can't you just add an `if(selectPackage == 'B') System.out.println("You saved 20 $");`?

Comment: Is there an error, or do you expect us to write code for you?

Comment: Your code is also not complete. There are a lot of missing closing `}`

Comment: @nem : I mean, For example : If user choose package A and the extra hours will be, 3 , his cost will be 15.95 and I want to tell the user that if you chose package B, you were saved 2 dollars because   ------------------ Package A : 9.95   10 hours access , extra hours/$2.00                   Package B : 13.95   20 hours access , extra hours/$1.00

Comment: @Pokechu22 : I mean, For example : If user choose package A and the extra hours will be, 3 , his cost will be 15.95 and I want to tell the user that if you chose package B, you were saved 2 dollars because ------------------ Package A : 9.95 10 hours access , extra hours/$2.00 Package B : 13.95 20 hours access , extra hours/$1.00

Comment: @dibagram I can't really help you without seeing all of your code, there is too much missing for me to see what your code is doing, please provide all of your code and I will try and assist you further.

Comment: @James : here you are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had a look through your code and have made *ALOT* of edits and improvements, the main issue I found was your use of `}` in the wrong places. I believe this was because you haven't organised your code very well; in future consider organising your code to make it easier to find errors, below I have corrected your code and have put the last few lines into a comment as I'm not sure why you have them there, if there are any questions about it, just ask me:

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char selectPackage; //To hold Internet Package
    double hourUsage, totalCharges, addCharges; //other variables
    //Create a Scanner object for keyboard input.
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    //Prompt the user to select a Internet Package.
    System.out.print("Which package did you purchase? ( Enter the Package's letter)");
    char input = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
    selectPackage = Character.toUpperCase(input);
    System.out.print("Please select the amount of hours used.");
    hourUsage = keyboard.nextDouble();
    //Display pricing for selected package...
    switch (selectPackage) {
        case 'A':
            if (hourUsage > 10) {
                addCharges = hourUsage - 10;
                totalCharges = (addCharges * 2.0) + 9.95;
                System.out.println("You have used " + hourUsage + " hours and your total is $" + totalCharges + " per month. "); 
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Your total is $9.95 per month.");
            }
        break;
        case 'B':
            if (hourUsage > 20 ) { 
                addCharges = hourUsage - 20;
                totalCharges = (addCharges * 1.0) + 13.95;
                System.out.println("You have used " + hourUsage + " and your total is $" + totalCharges + " per month.");
            }
            else{ 
                System.out.println("Your total is $13.95 per month.");
            } 
        break;
        case 'C':
            System.out.println("Your total is $19.95 per month.");
        break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid Choice. Choice A,B,C");
    }
    /**System.out.println("Your total is $19.95 per month.");
     System.out.println("Your total is $19.95 per month.");
     **/
}
}
```